# RAILS get website geolocation and title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have form where user puts website url and need to get its geolocation and title, like here: https://www.site24x7.com/find-website-location.html
I'm new in Rails and not sure if Geokit is a way to do this. Anyone can help how to start deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain old Ruby to handle most of it. You could use various gems to handle it...but the less dependencies you have the better! Here's an example...

```
# put this in the lib directory and name it location.rb
module Location
  require 'socket'
  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'

  def get_ip_address(url)
    IPSocket::getaddress(url)
  end

  def get_location_info(url)
    ip_address = get_ip_address(url)
    location = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://ipapi.co/#{ip_address}/json/"))
    JSON.parse(location)
  end

  module_function :get_ip_address
  module_function :get_location_info
end
```

The JSON that is returned from the get_location_info method will look like this....

```
{"ip"=>"108.163.210.34", "city"=>"Chicago", "region"=>"Illinois",
 "region_code"=>"IL", "country"=>"US", "country_name"=>"United States", 
"continent_code"=>"NA", "in_eu"=>false, "postal"=>"60604", "latitude"=>41.8776,
 "longitude"=>-87.6272, "timezone"=>"America/Chicago", "utc_offset"=>"-0500",
 "country_calling_code"=>"+1", "currency"=>"USD", "languages"=>"en-US,es-US,haw,fr", "asn"=>"AS32475", "org"=>"SingleHop LLC"}
```

So now you can `require 'location'` in your controller and use this method to get info

```
# at the top of your controller require 'location' 
def show
  # use a form that passes in the url to this show action to make it availabe in the params
  location_info = Location.get_location_info(params[:url])
  @ip = location_info["ip"]
  @city = location_info["city"]
  # other info you want to display in the view from location_info
end
```